# Conditional Format based on dates in Power BI

Tags: datetime, powerbi, conditional-formatting

I am trying to get a date/time in Power BI to conditionally format if it exceeds a certain date.

I found a formula that supposedly I could use to get the conditional formatting to work but the formula doesn't seem to work for me some reason; I am not familiar with Power Bi syntax.

I want the dispatch data to highlight if it passes the critical dispatch time.

[image]

I found the following as an example of what someone did to get their dates to conditionally format but I wasn't able to get their formula to work for me.

[image]

[image]

Here is what I tried doing in my power query:

[image]

Just for context, Leg 1 Dispatch = Dispatch in my columns.  I know this must be some sort of syntax issue but I can't seem to find a resource that helps me identify the issue.

Here is are the columns that I am trying to use, and the suggested formula that doesn't seem to 'find' those columns.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you were right on with creating a measure to calculate the difference and formatting based on the measure.

Your immediate error (`Token Eof expected.`) is just saying your parenthesis don't match. In this case, you have a `)` after `[#"Critical Dispatch Time (Local)"]`, but no preceding function or `(`.

It's unclear from the question, but if you are creating a custom column that only references columns in the same table, the MAX() function is not needed. The purpose of the MAX() function in the tutorial was to aggregate and consolidate multiple values to a single value if needed. However, in a custom column on the same table as the dates you are referencing, the immediate context is just the current row. Hence, you can simply write:

```
IF( [Leg 1 Dispatch Date (Local)] > [Critical Dispatch Time (Local)], 1, 0 )
```

If you are writing a measure that can be run over any context, then it is necessary to properly handle the potential for multiple values. We can just tweak it a little using the SELECTEDVALUE() function, which only returns the value when the there is a single distinct result (otherwise it returns blank or another user-defined expression).

```
IF( 
    SELECTEDVALUE([Leg 1 Dispatch Date (Local)] ) 
        > SELECTEDVALUE([Critical Dispatch Time (Local)] ), 
    1, 0
)
```

Either a custom column or a custom measure will work for this, but a measure is slightly preferable on a large dataset because it is only computed if needed.

Either way you choose (measure/column), just set your rule formatting to only trigger when the expression is 1.

Comment: Hmm, what you explain here makes complete sense but I am not able to make either work correctly.  I am getting an error for the custom column option saying I spelled IF wrong (like really?), then for the measure option, I get the following error: The value for '#"Leg 1 Dispatch Date (local)' cannot be determined. Either the column doesn't exist, or there is no current row for this column.

Comment: On the column error, what is the exact message you are getting? On the measure error, I just used the measure names from your screenshot, assuming you columns were named the same. You may need to tweak the column references to match what you have in your model.

Comment: Ah, my custom column was in DAX, not query editor. The PowerQuery equivalent would be: if [#"Leg 1 Dispatch Date (Local)"] > [#"Critical Dispatch Time (Local)"] then 1 else 0. Everything always is dependent on your data structure and requirements, but I would say the measure is your best way to go here for performance and simplicity.

Comment: In the custom column (if its done in the query editor) you have to write it in lower case, this means you have to write `if` and not `IF`. You are mixing (based) on your screenshot on top `Power Query M` and `DAX`. In the query editor you work with `Power Query M` and outside the query editor you write in `DAX`. `IF( [#"Leg 1 Dispatch Date (Local)"] > [#"Critical Dispatch Time (Local)"], 1, 0 )` this is `DAX`. In `Power Query M` it would be `if [#"Leg 1 Dispatch Date (Local)"] > [#"Critical Dispatch Time (Local)"] then 1 else 0`

Comment: Ok, I am understanding the Power Query M vs DAX a little more now.  Still having an issue with the columns not being found for some reason.  I have included an image in the original post showing the 2 columns that I am trying to use with the formula in the measure.

Comment: Take out the `#"` and the `"` from the the column references. Those are only needed in PowerQuery.

Comment: Ok, very much a user error on my part as I am still learning Power Bi.  For whatever reason, I was clicking the measure button and it wasn't adding a column with the measure.  Instead, I added a column in the table and typed the formula and it worked perfectly.  Thank you all for your patience and help!  @luke_0 Yes, I did that too.  Thank you!